# How can I receive notifications using Pusher in Flutter App when app is not running in the background

Tags: flutter, pusher

I'm using pusher package(pusher_websocket_flutter: ^0.2.0
)to send a notification. It works great when the app is open or when it is put in the background. It works as expected.
One issue that I'm facing is I'm not able to receive the notifications when the app is not in the background or when the app is cleared from the background. Any possible solutions?

This is the code that I have done so far.
//Method to connect to the pusher

```
Future<void> firePusher(String channelName,String videoCallChannel, 
String eventName,String videoCallEvent) async {
await initPusher();
connectPusher();
// await subscribePusher(videoCallChannel);
await subscribePusher(channelName);
bindEvent(eventName,'chanelName');
}
```

And inside the bind method, I have the following code which shows the notification when a mail arrives...

```
   channel.bind(eventName,(last){
    final String data = last.data;
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
    print("Data from Mail : $data");
    _inEventData.add(data);
    _showNotification();
  });
```

If I want to achieve when the notification comes and my app is not running in the background what should I do?

Comment: Can someone please let me know anything i can try.

Comment: This might be helpful to you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688519/flutter-push-notification-is-working-only-when-app-is-in-background

Answer (score 0):

Search how to run this pusher package as background service.