# Where should put the condition to send push notification in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

I would like to build an app like when I save a new data with latitude and longitude information to firebase then in my app I calculate the distance between these latitude&longitude and the user's current location. If the distance is less than 60 kilometres then send an `onBackgroundMessage` notification. I do not store the user's current location on firebase. I get the user's current location with function `_getCurrentLocation`.
The problem is that I do not undertsand where and how to put the `isValidDistance` to check if the distance is under 60 kilimetres.
Currently my app send notifications but not by distance.

index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
    .document("animal/{message}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("animal", {
        data: {
          latitude: snapshot.data()["latitude"].toString(),
          longitude: snapshot.data()["longitude"].toString(),
        },
        notification: {
          title: snapshot.data().username,
          body: snapshot.data().description,
          clickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        },
      });
    });
```

main.dart

```
Future<void> _messageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('background message ${message.data}');
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double? currentLatitude;
  double? currentLongitude;

  Future<void> _getCurrentLocation() async {
    final locData = await Location().getLocation();
    setState(() {
      currentLatitude = locData.latitude;
      currentLongitude = locData.longitude;
    });
  }

  int getDistanceInMeters(currLat, currLng, lat, lng) {
    return Geolocator.distanceBetween(
      currLat,
      currLng,
      lat,
      lng,
    ).round();
  }

  bool isValidDistance(RemoteMessage messaging) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = messaging.data;
    var _list = data.values.toList();
    var lat = double.parse(_list[0]);
    var lng = double.parse(_list[1]);
    print(_list);
    int distance =
        getDistanceInMeters(currentLatitude, currentLongitude, lat, lng);
    var distanceInKm = (distance / 1000).round();

    print('Distance is: ${distanceInKm.toString()}');
    if (distance < 60000) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentLocation();
    final messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    messaging.subscribeToTopic('animal');

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      if (isValidDistance(message)) {
        print('onMessageListen');
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      if (isValidDistance(message)) {
        print('onMessageOpened');
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_messageHandler);
  }
...
```

Comment: Currently which of your print statement logs when you get a notification?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand it. The 
`if (isValidDistance(message)) {
        print('onMessageOpened');
      }`
 statement prints the log when the distance is valid. I wrote this statement just checking my code and was trying to understand the sending push notification. Currently I get all notification and I do not know how can I do that If there is a new data in the ```animal``` on firebase then  first check the distance before sending push notification.

Comment: Do you get notification when app is opened currently and location is not valid? Because you have handle the notification while app is opened using the onmessage. However for notification when app is closed you need to create a platform specific channel to handle while in backgrund. Check out https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124.

Comment: No. When app is opened I do not get any notification. It just print log "onMessageListen" when the distance is valid.
So I cannot handle push notification by distance on flutter when app is closed? The only way to handle this if I do it in android and ios folder?

Comment: Yes that is how it works for . 
Also going through your code, you are sending a notification message, so firebase displays it automatically when the app is in background. Check this to get the difference between data messages and notification messages https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages . 
You can handlle data messages in background with FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage() but it must be a top level function.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change your fcm from notification message to data message to allow app handle messages while in background. Check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
.document("animal/{message}")
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("animal", {
    data: {
      latitude: snapshot.data()["latitude"].toString(),
      longitude: snapshot.data()["longitude"].toString(),
      title: snapshot.data().username,
      body: snapshot.data().description,
    },
  });
});
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688519/flutter-push-notification-is-working-only-when-app-is-in-background) to show push notification while app is open. Your code should like this.

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
if (isValidDistance(message)) {
    print('onMessageListen');
    showNotification(message);
  }
});
```

Yo can access the data sent through the following

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = message.data;
```

Then the background handler will be as follows.

```
_messageHandler(RemoteMessaging message){
if (isValidDistance(message)) {
        print('onMessageListen');
        showNotification(message);
      }
}
```

Or create a Notification class as follows and use.

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', // id
  'High Importance Notifications', // title
  description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
  importance: Importance.max,
);

Future<LocationData> _getCurrentLocation() => Location().getLocation();

int getDistanceInMeters(currLat, currLng, lat, lng) {
  return Geolocator.distanceBetween(
    currLat,
    currLng,
    lat,
    lng,
  ).round();
}

Future<bool> isValidDistance(RemoteMessage messaging) async {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = messaging.data;
  var _list = data.values.toList();
  var lat = double.parse(_list[0]);
  var lng = double.parse(_list[1]);
  print(_list);
  var location = await _getCurrentLocation();
  int distance =
      getDistanceInMeters(location.latitude, location.longitude, lat, lng);
  var distanceInKm = (distance / 1000).round();

  print('Distance is: ${distanceInKm.toString()}');
  if (distance < 60000) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

class NotificationServices {
  final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    bool isValid = await isValidDistance(message);
    if (isValid) {
      print('onMessageListen');
      showNotification(message);
    }
  }

  backgroundNotification() {
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    final AndroidInitializationSettings _initialzationSettingsAndriod =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    final IOSInitializationSettings _initialzationSettingsIOS =
        IOSInitializationSettings();
    final InitializationSettings _initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: _initialzationSettingsAndriod,
            iOS: _initialzationSettingsIOS);
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
    /// heads up notifications.
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(_initializationSettings);

    FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage? message) async {
      if (message != null) await onClickNotificationHandler(message);
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      bool isValid = await isValidDistance(message);
      if (isValid) {
        print('onMessageListen');
        showNotification(message);
      }
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      await onClickNotificationHandler(message);
    });
  }

  onClickNotificationHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = message.data;
    print(data);
    //you can handle notificationand navigate to necessary  screen here.
  }

  showNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = message.data;
    if (data["body"] != null) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        data.hashCode,
        data["title"],
        data["body"],
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description,
            icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
          ),
          iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(
              presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me to get notification by distance when app is opened. But unfortunately I get error onBackgroundMessage: ```Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#lyokone/location( 8008): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$Result com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocation.getLocationResult' on a null object reference```
I get this error, when I try to call the method ```isValidDistance(message)```.

Comment: By the way how should call the Notification class?
I tried to call in the initState in the main.dart, but it does not send any notification.
```@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    NotificationServices();
```

Comment: Yes in initstate
NotificationService().backgroundNotification();

Comment: For the exception, I think you might need ti implement platfrm specific code.