# Flutter Firebase Pushnotification not working when App is not in memory

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am **receiving notifications when app is running in foreground or in background** but problem is **when app is closed or killed from memory, I am not getting any notification.** I have searched every where. But not a single blog or post helped me. Other stuffs are working perfectly. Please do help me to find that solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Can you check this [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/41) which might help you?  Can you provide the code what you have implemented and can you mention the Firebase SDK version?

Comment: Also you may go through this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688519/flutter-push-notification-is-working-only-when-app-is-in-background).